# Group the Numbers With the Same Sum

Tags: code-golf

Your task is, given a square grid of digits (`0-9`), output one of the ways that the digits can be grouped such that:

1. Each digit is part of exactly one group
2. All groups have the same number of digits
3. All groups are bounded by one polygon-like shape (this means that every digit in the group is next to [left, right, up, down] at least one other digit of the same group, unless each group has 1 element).
4. All groups have the same sum

The input grid will always be a square:
You may choose any input method you would like (including supplying arguments to a function or method). In addition, the input will supply the number of groups that your program should group the digits into.

Example input:

Suppose your input format is `stringOfDigits numberOfGroups`.

An example input would be:

```
156790809 3
```

which would translate to (a grid of `sqrt(9) * sqrt(9)`)

```
1 5 6
7 9 0
8 0 9
```

which you would have to divide into 3 groups, each of which should have `9 / 3 = 3` elements with the same sum.

Output:
Output should be the string of digits, with optional spaces and newlines for formatting, with each digit followed by a letter `a-z` indicating its group. There should be exactly `numberOfTotalDigits / numberOfGroups` elements in each group. You will never have to divide something into more than 26 groups.

Example output:

```
1a 5a 6b
7c 9a 0b
8c 0c 9b
```

Note that replacing all `a`s with `b`s and `b`s with `a`s is equally valid. As long as each group is denoted by a distinct letter, the output is valid.

In addition, I expect most programs to output something along the lines of this, because newlines/spaces are optional:

```
1a5a6b7c9a0b8c0c9b
```

In this case, adding all digits of group `a`, `b`, or `c` makes 15. In addition, all groups are bound by some polygon.

Invalid outputs:

```
1a 5a 6b
7c 9a 0c
8c 0b 9b
```

because the groups do not form polygons (specifically, the `6b` is isolated and `0c` is also lonely).

```
1a 5a 6b
7c 9a 0b
8c 0b 9b
```

because the group `b` has 4 elements while `c` only has 2.

Etc.

If there is no valid solution, your program may do anything (i.e. stop, crash, run forever) but if your program prints `None` when there is no valid solution, `-15` to your score.

If there is more than one solution, you only have to print one, but `-20` if your program prints all of them separated by some delimiter.

This is code golf, so shortest code (with bonuses) wins!

Comment: In the first invalid output, I think you mean the `6b` is isolated, not the `0b`.

Comment: Does it matter how fast our program is? What about if it's too slow to validate if it works?

Comment: `156790889 3` seems like it should be `156790809 3`

Answer (score 10):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 122 - 20 - 15 = 87

```
=Z/lzQ=ks^lz.5Jm]dUzL[-bk+bk?tb%bkb?hb%hbkb)FNJIgNZB~Jm+NksmybN;|jbS{msm+@zk@S*Z<GQxsdkUzfqSsTUz^fqsmv@*ZzbY/smvdzQJQ"None
```

Changes:

- 130 -> 120: Switched to newline separated input.
- 120 -> 134: Fixed a bug involving groups not of size equal to the side length of the matrix.
- 134 -> 120: Prints all solutions, including ones equivalent under group renaming.
- 120 -> 122: Fixed a bug where only paths would be generated, instead of all legal groups.

Test run:

```
pyth programs/sum_group.pyth <<< '156790809
3'
1a5a6b7c9a0b8c0c9b
1a5a6c7b9a0c8b0b9c
1b5b6a7c9b0a8c0c9a
1b5b6c7a9b0c8a0a9c
1c5c6a7b9c0a8b0b9a
1c5c6b7a9c0b8a0a9b


pyth programs/sum_group.pyth <<< '156790808
3'
None

pyth programs/sum_group.pyth <<< '1111     
2'
1a1a1b1b
1a1b1a1b
1b1a1b1a
1b1b1a1a
```

Explanation:

```
Pyth code           (Pseudo)-Python code              Comments

(implicit)          z = input()                       z is the digit string
(implicit)          Q = eval(input())                 S is the number of groups
(implicit)          G = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
=Z/lzQ              Z = len(z)/Q                      Z is the size of each group.
=ks^lz.5            k = int(len(z) ** .5)             k is the side length of the matrix.
Jm]dUz              J = map(lambda d:[d], range(len(z))) Locations are encoded as numbers.
L                   def y(b): return                  y will be the transition function.
 [-bQ                         [b-k,                   Move up - the row above is k less.
  +bQ                          b+k,                   Move down - the row below is k more.
  ?tb%bkb                      b-1 if b%k else b      Move left, unless at the left edge.
  ?hb%hbkb)                    b+1 if (b+1)%k else b] Move right, unless at right edge.
FNJ                 for N in J:                       This constructs the list of all
   IgNZB                       if N[Z-1]: break       Z-length connected groups.
   ~Jm+Nk                      J+=map(lambda k: N+[k],  Append to J the group of N +
      smybN                          sum(map(lambda b:  anything reachable from
                                     y(b),N)))        anywhere in N.
   ;                (end for)
|                   or                                Print first truthy thing between
 S{                 sorted(set(                       Unique elements in sorted order of
   ms               map(lambda b:sum(                 Map+sum over allowable combinations
     m+@zd          map(lambda d:z[d]+                Character in original digit string
       @S*Z<GQ      sorted(G[:Q]*Z)[                  Repeated and sorted early alphabet
        xsbd        sum(b).index(d)],                 At index of number in sum of groups
      Uz                range(len(z)))                Over possible indexes.
   f                filter(lambda T:                  To generate allowable combinations, 
                                                      we will filter all groups of Q paths.
    qSsTUz          sorted(sum(T)) == range(len(z))   Ensure all locations are visited.
    ^                                                 Combinations of
     f              filter(lambda Y:                  Filter over connected Z-length groups
      qsm           equal(sum(map(lambda k:           Sum of the values of the group
         v@*ZzkY    eval((z*Z)[k]),Y)                 In the original digit string
       /smvbzQ      sum(map(lambda b:eval(b),z))/Q    must equal the sum of all values in z
                                                      divided by the number of groups.
      J             J                                 Filter over connected Z-length groups
     Q              Q                                 Combinations of length Q
 "None              "None"                            If the above was empty, print "None"
```

Comment: "Pyth"? You misspelled "base64".

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) 361 (376-15) <s>372</s>

(Maybe can still be golfed a little more)

As a function, first param is the string of digits and second param is the number of groups.
It's a naive recursive search, stopping at first solution found (no -20 bonus).
Need some more test cases to verify performance on some bigger input.

```javascript
F=(g,n,l=g.length,i=w=Math.sqrt(l),o=s=h='',
  R=(g,p,k,j=l/n,t=s/n,v=0,h=String.fromCharCode(97+k))=>(
    t-=g[p],!(t<0)&&(
      g=[...g],g[p]=h,
      S=f=>g.some((c,p)=>c<':'&&f(p)),
      --j?S(p=>(g[p+1]==h|g[p-1]==h|g[p+w+1]==h|g[p-w-1]==h)?v=R(g,p,k,j,t):0)
      :t?0:k?S(p=>v=R(g,p,k-1)):v=g
    ),v
  )
)=>([for(c of g)(s-=-c,h+=--i?c:(i=w,c+':'))],h=R(g=h,-1,n,1))?h.map((c,p)=>o+=c!=':'?g[p]+c:'')&&o:'None'
```

**Ungolfed & Explained**

```javascript
F=(g,n)=> 
{
  var l = g.length, // string size, group size is l/n 
      w = Math.sqrt(l), // width of grid
      s,i,h,o;

  // Build a new string in h, adding rows delimiters that will act as boundary markers  
  // At the same time calculate the total sum of all digits
  h='',  // Init string
  s = 0, // Init sum 
  i = w, // Init running counter for delimiters
  [for(c of g)(
    s -= -c, // compute sum using minus to avoid string concatenation
    h += --i ? c : (i=w, c+':') // add current char + delimiter when needed
  )];


  // Recursive search
  // Paramaters:
  // g : current grid array, during search used digits are replaced with group letters
  // p : current position
  // k : current group id (start at n, decreaseing)
  // j : current group size, start at l/n decreasing, at 0 goto next group id
  // t : current group sum value, start at s/n decreasing

  var R=(g,p,k,j,t)=> 
  {
    var v = 0, // init value to return is 0
        h = String.fromCharCode(97+k); // group letter from group

    t-=g[p]; // subtract current digit

    if (t<0) // exceed the sum value, return 0 to stop search and backtrak
      return 0;

    g=[...g]; // build a new array from orginal parameter
    g[p] = h; // mark current position

    // Utility function  to scan grid array
    // call worker function  f only for digit elements
    //   skipping group markers, row delimieters and out of grid values (that are undefined)  
    // Using .some will return ealry if f returns truthy  
    var S=f=>g.some((c,p)=>c<':'&&f(p));

    if (--j) // decrement current group size, if 0 then group completed
    { // if not 0
      // Scan grid to find cells adiacent to current group and call R for each 
      S( p => {
        if (g[p+1]==h|g[p-1]==h|g[p+w+1]==h|g[p-w-1]==h) // check if adiacent to a mark valued h
        {
          return v=R(g,p,k,j,t) // set v value and returns it
        }
      })
      // here v could be 0 or a full grid 
    }
    else
    {
      // special case: at first call, t is be NaN because p -1 (outside the grid)
      // to start a full grid serach
      if (t) // check if current reached 0
        return 0; // if not, return 0 to stop search and backtrak


      if (k) // check if current group completed
      {
        // if not at last group, recursive call to R to check next group 
        S( p => {
          // exec the call for each valid cell still in grid
          // params j and t start again at init values
          return v=R(g,p,k-1,l/n,s/n) // set value v and returns it
        })
        // here v could be 0 or a full grid 
      }
      else
      {
        return g; // all groups checked, search OK, return grid with all groups marked
      }
    }
    return v
  };
  g = h; // set g = h, so g has the row boundaries and all the digits

  h=R(h,-1,n,1); // first call with position -1 to and group size 1 to start a full grid search

  if (h) // h is the grid with group marked if search ok, else h is 0
  {
    o = ''; // init output string
    // build output string merging the group marks in h and the original digits in g
    h.map( (c,p) => o += c>':' ? g[p]+c: '') // cut delimiter ':'
    return o;
  }
  return 'None';
}
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

`F("156790809",3)` output `1c5c6b7a9c0b8a0a9b`

`F("156790819",3)` output `None`